# Next.js project not starting after syncing files with Google Drive on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, npm, next.js, file-permissions, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a Next.js project that was working fine until I installed Google Drive and synced my files. After the sync, I'm unable to start my project. When I try to run npm run dev, the server starts but then hangs and doesn't fully load the application. The output I get is:

`

> twitchclone@0.1.0 dev 
> next dev -p 3001
> ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3001, url: http://localhost:3001
> info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\da\Desktop\coding\Odin-work Advanced\TwitchClone.env
> `

I've tried several things to fix this:

1. Checked if the port 3001 is being used by another process.
2. Tried running the project on a different port.
3. Restarted my computer.
4. Checked my Windows Defender Firewall settings.
5. Checked my hosts file.
6. Upgraded Node.js and npm to the latest versions.
7. Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalled the packages.
   -None of these steps have resolved the issue.

I've noticed that I'm unable to delete the node_modules folder due to a permission issue. The owner of the folder is my user account, but I still get a message saying I need permission from my user account to make changes to the folder.

Interestingly, I created a new Next.js project using create-t3-app after uninstalling Google Drive, and it works fine. I can start the server with npm run dev and I can delete the node_modules folder without any permission issues.

I suspect that Google Drive may have changed some file permissions or attributes when I tried to sync my files, but I'm not sure how to confirm this or fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My '.env' file has not changed, I haven't done any real work in these files since last week, however I did try to backup some files temporarily to google drive since one of my HDD's died, which is why I suspect that this could be the source of the issue.